# Facebook graph api syntax

Tags: json, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I successfully able to pull from facebook by setting my url as

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/357548020948379/posts?access_token=XXXXX";
```

Now when I try to pass on some fields for posts such as full_picture, message, and permalink it gives me a 400 error.

meanwhile I was able to do it in facebook's developer tool. The below line was generated by facebook graph api explorer.

I think I did something syntactically wrong? Also should I use javascript SDK from facebook or I'm fine with using ajax via jquery like I normally would?

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/357548020948379/?fields=posts%7Bfull_picture%2Cmessage%2Cpermalink_url%7D&access_token=XXXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out. 
For those who are new to this and worry about syntax. Head over to facebook graph explorer and at the end of the page there's a button called "get codes" then look for curl version of it, strip all the unnecessary stuff and you have got your url.

I should point out to access facebook json object is usually pretty deep down. I simply play around with console log until I get it to out put what I want.

I had to go as deep as `console.log(data.posts.data[2].message)` to get to my data.